# same event emitting is happening just once instead of 2

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

the problem I have is that this.$emit is happening just once and I'm calling the event 2 times, I tried to figure it out but not luck so far, does somebody knows?

the idea behind is to emit and event and when the information is received then emit the event again to toggle the component

Form.vue

```
    <template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="text-left">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" v-model="username"/>
            <label for="likes">Number of likes</label>
            <input type="text" id="likes" class="form-control" v-model="likes"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-center">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
              <label>Bots available</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <div class="pull-left">
                <select>
                  <option>Bot 1</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="submit" :disabled="username.length == 0 || likes.length == 0 ">Start</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
      data(){
        return{
          username : '',
          likes: ''
        }
      },
      props:['loadingChange'],
      methods:{
        async submit(){
         try {
        this.$emit('loadingChange')

           await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/botwork')
        
        this.$emit('loadingChange')

         } catch (error) {
           console.log(error)
         }
          // console.log(this.username.length,this.likes.length)
        }
      }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

App.vue

```
    <template>
  <div id="app">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-form v-if="!loading" @loadingChange='loading=!loading'></app-form>
    <!-- <hr /> -->
    <!-- <app-footer ></app-footer> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import Footer from "./components/Footer.vue";
import Header from "./components/Header.vue";
import Form from "./components/Form.vue";

export default {
  data(){
    return{
      loading: false
    }
  },
  components: {
    // appFooter: Footer,
    appHeader: Header,
    appForm: Form,
  }
 
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: You toggle the condition which renders the element, so it runs once and is then removed from the DOM. Also, I don't actually see where it's emitting twice, `submit` is only called once. Side note: you don't need `loadingChange` declared as a prop

Comment: Hey Daniel, Thank you I will correct the prop you are right and modify my code now I'm emitting twice but still not working, I tough that v-if didn't remove from the DOM was more than hidding, then I should do it with CSS?

Comment: `v-if` removes from the DOM, `v-show` sets `display: none`/`display: block`. Try that and see if it helps